# Group if COUNT(*) > X, otherwise don't group items

Tags: mysql, group-by, having-clause

I'm trying to return a list of map items from my DB grouping the items ONLY if the group count is greater than 4 otherwise I don't want the items to be grouped.

My project is built to return all entries within a set area and I'll be using grouping to break up that area into a grid. If each cell in the grid has too many results then I will show a group marker with the group count instead of a single entry marker.

My current query works to determine if there are grouped items by the COUNT(*)

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) as groupCount, floor(longitude/0.0007) AS groupLong, floor(latitude/0.0007) AS groupLat 
FROM items 
WHERE longitude>=151.1 
    AND longitude<=151.2 
    AND latitude>=-33.9 
    AND latitude<=-33.8 
GROUP BY floor(longitude/0.0007), floor(latitude/0.0007)
```

What I would like to do is only group the items if the group count > 4 and items in a group <=4 will be returned as ungrouped items.

I know that I can use `HAVING COUNT(*)>4` to only return the groups of 5 and over but what can I do to return the ungrouped items that would be in the groups of 4 and under?

I would be happy to do two queries to get the results but if there was a way of doing it in one then that would be great!

Comment: If you have the option of switching database engines, this would be a good use case for window functions. MySQL doesn't support them (that I can find), but PostgreSQL does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a SQL Fiddle for my solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/e40ba/1

The idea is to first figure out what the groups will be, which is done in the subquery `grouping`. We then join these groups to the original table, but we use a left outer join so any value that isn't in a group will get have nulls for the grouping columns. Finally, we use `AVG` to come up with a representative coordinate for the group. For ungrouped values, this will be the coordinate itself, which is nice.

I would recommend against actually using this without doing some testing and benchmarking. That join is probably going to be terrible if `items` is large. I really just wanted to find a way to do this in a single query. As I said in my comment, the right way to do this would be to use window functions, but MySQL doesn't have those.

```
SELECT AVG(longitude) AS longitude
     , AVG(latitude) AS latitude
     , COUNT(*) AS count

FROM items
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS group_count
               , FLOOR(longitude/0.0007) AS group_longitude
               , FLOOR(latitude/0.0007) AS group_latitude
          FROM items
          -- Repeat the filter to avoid computing unnecessary groups
          WHERE longitude >= 151.1
            AND longitude <= 151.2
            AND latitude >= -33.9
            AND latitude <= -33.8
          GROUP BY group_longitude, group_latitude
          HAVING group_count > 4
        ) AS grouping
    -- Match each row up with its group
    ON FLOOR(longitude/0.0007) = group_longitude
    AND FLOOR(latitude/0.0007) = group_latitude

WHERE longitude >= 151.1
  AND longitude <= 151.2
  AND latitude >= -33.9
  AND latitude <= -33.8

GROUP BY COALESCE(group_longitude, id)
       , COALESCE(group_latitude, id)
```

Comment: Really really great idea. In my case, on millions of rows, grouping without condition is 80ms, with condition (this strategy) its about 160ms. So not super fast

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use union the two subquery result to solve this problem. Perhaps you can use the subselect by divide the two part, first part got the COUNT(*)>4 condition result, the second got the  other items.id then retrieve the all other items.